# cherry-picking with git-svn

Tags: svn, git, cherry-pick

I'm facing the problem of merging a subset of revisions from one topic-branch to another. Since I am using git-svn, I was curious to see if it is possible to use cherry-picking for this. Using Subversion, I would do:

```
svn merge -c A
svn merge -c B
svn merge -c C
...
svn commit ...
```

what will happen if I try to do this?

```
git checkout branch1
git cherry-pick A
git cherry-pick B
git cherry-pick C
git svn dcommit
```

If I read the git svn man-page, the answers is "don't do that", but I get the impression when googling around that git svn does a much better job now with these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do `git svn dcommit`, it will sequentially run an `svn commit` for each git commit between your svn tracking branch and whatever `HEAD` is in git. In your example, that's three commits – one each for A, B, and C – since `git cherry-pick` commits the changes right away. Granted, you could use `git rebase -i` to squash those commits together into a single revision before you run `git svn dcommit` to push them to svn.

Running `git-svn` completely ignores all `svn:mergeinfo` properties. From the [`git-svn` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

> We ignore all SVN properties except svn:executable. Any unhandled properties are logged to `$GIT_DIR/svn/<refname>/unhandled.log`

Comment: I use TortoiseSVN, so I'm not sure how you'd do it on the command line, but I would recommend doing what in Tortoise is referred to as Recording the Merge, where you update the mergeinfo, but don't make any actual changes in the commit.  This would theoretically prevent further issues if other people do merges within the SVN context, since those revisions have already been "merged" and might cause a false conflict.

Answer (score 9):

*git-svn* had a serious problem related to cherry-picked commits:

Suppose you have commit *a1b2c3f9* which is already dcommitted into svn repository:

```
  $ git show a1b2c3f9
  commit a1b2c3f9...
  Author: Happy Dev <happyd@43fe5c0-...>
  Date:   Mon Nov 14 13:01:38 2011 +0000

  Commit message

  git-svn-id: https://host/svn/branches/some-branch@1000 43fe5c0-...
```

See this *git-svn-id* line? This is how *git-svn* understands where your commit lies in Subversion repository.

Now you want to cherry-pick this commit to *master* branch you're currently on:

```
  $ git cherry-pick a1b2c3f9
```

If there were no merge conflicts, git creates a new commit, say, *9f3c2b1a* and here what we have:

```
  $ git show 9f3c2b1a
  commit 9f3c2b1a...
  Author: Happy Dev <happyd@43fe5c0-...>
  Date:   Mon Nov 14 13:01:39 2011 +0000

  Commit message

  git-svn-id: https://host/svn/branches/some-branch@1000 43fe5c0-...
```

So, Git created a commit with exactly the same message. This caused serious problems. Former versions of *git-svn* sent such commit into wrong branch — *^/branches/some-branch* instead of *^/trunk/*.

This problem is already fixed in the latest versions of Git. But there is another one which is still present:

*git-svn* doesn't honor merge-tracking mechanism of Subversion.

Subversion tracks merge information on performed cherry-picks, so the command

```
  $ svn merge -c 1000 ^/branches/some-branch trunk-working-copy
```

adjusts the *svn:mergeinfo* property of *trunk-working-copy* as follows:

```
  + /branches/some-branch: 1000
```

This way Subversion understands that this particular revision was already merged into *^/trunk/* branch thus it skips this change in further merges.

When you run `git cherry-pick` and then `git svn dcommit` Subversion repository doesn't get *svn:mergeinfo* modification.

---

Here goes the disclaimer:
Currently I don't work on [SmartGit](http://syntevo.com/smartgit/) but I work in a close contact with SmartGit developers.

[Syntevo](http://syntevo.com/) company developed [SmartGit](http://syntevo.com/smartgit/) — a great replacement of *git-svn*. This Git client resolves all the issues I've described above:

So, you cherry-pick *a1b2c3f9* commit:

```
  $ git cherry-pick a1b2c3f9
```

as result you get *9f3c2b1a* commit, and then you push it into Subversion repository. SmartGit does everything to keep merge-tracking information, so *^/trunk/* branch gets necessary modification of its *svn:mergeinfo* property:

```
  + /branches/some-branch: 1000
```

You can perform Git cherry-pick either from SmartGit itself or using Git command line interface. In the second case commit message should have *git-svn-id* line of the cherry-pick source.

SmartGit is proprietary software but it's free for non-commercial usage. It has a lot of great features, for more information please refer to  [SmartGit documentation](http://syntevo.com/git-svn/index.html).

There is another interesting project which solves certain problems with *git-svn* — [SubGit](http://subgit.com). Basically it is the server-side solution for synchronizing changes between Subversion and Git repositories. It's much more superior than *git-svn* and doesn't have its problems.

As svn-via-git user, I believe, you might be interested in that too.

Comment: > It's much more superior than git-svn and doesn't have its problems. 

This is claimed everythere on the SubGit website, but I can't find anything in detail what they are able to do and how they handle the structural differences.

Comment: I know this is old, but do you have any references for the claim that this problem is fixed in git?


`So, Git created a commit with exactly the same message. This caused serious problems. Former versions of git-svn sent such commit into wrong branch — ^/branches/some-branch instead of ^/trunk/.

This problem is already fixed in the latest versions of Git.`

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem with this at all; I've done this many times at work before.  Additionally, when TortoiseSVN has had trouble merging entire branches in the past, I have resorted to rebasing topic branches on top of trunk and squashing all the commits into one commit, which is similar in nature to a cherry-pick.  It's worked great.

Comment: But will git svn update svn:mergeinfo properties correctly so that subsequence merge operations done with svn merge will "see" the cherry-picks?

Comment: @JesperE: No. For my work I don't care, because svn:mergeinfo is a terrible hack, and I use Git to perform merges anyway. :)

Comment: Yes, svn:mergeinfo is a terrible hack, but unfortunately, I don't have that luxury. My coworkers would get pretty annoyed if I did that.

Comment: Then I guess your answer is "don't do that."

Comment: git svn dcommit has a `--mergeinfo` option recently added.